# Android Studio aidl is missing

Tags: android-studio

```
compileSdkVersion  21
buildToolsVersion "22.0.1"

defaultConfig {
   applicationId "org.xyz.abc"
   minSdkVersion 16
   targetSdkVersion 21
}
```

> classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.2.3'

**Error getting -**

> Error:Execution failed for task ':app:compileDebugAidl'.
>   java.lang.IllegalStateException: aidl is missing

Answer (score 0):

Change build tool version to "21"

buildToolVersion and compileSdkVersion should be same